# Mysql query optimization with group by

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

can you suggest some tuning techniques or can you optimize this?

```
SELECT
    SUM(SkusClosingStock.closing_stock) AS closing_stock,
    SUM(SkusClosingStock.closing_pending_stock) AS closing_pending_stock,
    SUM(SkusClosingStock.closing_bad_stock + SkusClosingStock.closing_damaged_stock) AS closing_bad_stock,
    SUM(GREATEST(SkusClosingStock.is_low_stock, 1)) AS low_stock,
    SUM(GREATEST(SkusClosingStock.closing_stock, 1)) AS stock_out,
    skus.id
FROM
    skus_closing_stocks AS SkusClosingStock
 JOIN
    (
        SELECT id
        FROM skus
        WHERE company_id = '8308'
    ) AS skus ON skus.id = SkusClosingStock.sku_id
GROUP BY SkusClosingStock.sku_id limit 1000;
```

Explain outcome

```
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'skus', NULL, 'ref', 'PRIMARY,idx_skus_company_id,idx_co_lowstock', 'idx_skus_company_id', '5', 'const', '377590', '100.00', 'Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort'
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'SkusClosingStock', NULL, 'ref', 'idx_skus_closing_stocks_sku_id_warehouse_id', 'idx_skus_closing_stocks_sku_id_warehouse_id', '4', 'primary_db.skus.id', '11', '100.00', NULL
```

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions and your index definitions in addition to the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: Move `skus` and a condition by its column from the subquery to the query. Create suitable indices if not exists.